# Fastlane iOS is not working. Cloning remote git repo... is showing while fetch certificate and provisioning profile

Tags: ios, git, github, match, fastlane

I am trying to upload build using fastlane. Video which I am using for implementation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Jz-Ywxki0U&t=325s

I also using fastlane official documents for integrating it to deploy app on testflight.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/

I also Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent:

https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

This is project folder structure:

[image]

When I run the command:

```
$fastlane match init
```

Then Match file is created.

This is Match file:

[image]

This is Fastfile:

```
platform :ios do

before_all do
# ---------------
  ENV["FASTLANE_USER"] = "<email-id>"
  ENV["FASTLANE_PASSWORD"] = "<correct_password>"
  ENV["FASTLANE_TEAM_NAME"] = "<Team_Name"
  ENV["FASTLANE_ITC_TEAM_NAME"] = "<Team_Name>"

# ---------------
  ENV["PRODUCE_APP_IDENTIFIER"] = "<Bundle_Identifier>"
  ENV["PRODUCE_APP_NAME"] = "FastLaneHureka3"
  ENV["PRODUCE_VERSION"] = "0.1.0"
  ENV["PRODUCE_SKU"] = "FastLaneDemo3"
  ENV["PRODUCE_PLATFORM"] = "ios"

# ---------------

  ENV["MATCH_USERNAME"] = "<email-id>"
  ENV["MATCH_PASSWORD"] = "<correct_password>"
  ENV["MATCH_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"] = "<correct_password>"
  ENV["MATCH_GIT_URL"] = "git@github.com:ajeetsharma16/FastlaneCertficates.git"
  ENV["MATCH_APP_IDENTIFIER"] = "<Bundle_ID>"
  ENV["MATCH_TYPE"] = "appstore"
  ENV["MATCH_PLATFORM"] = "ios"
  ENV["MATCH_VERBOSE"] = "true"

end

  desc "Create on developer portal and App Store connect"

  lane :create_app do 

  create_app_online #produce

  end

  desc "Sync signing"
  lane :signing do

match(git_private_key:"/Users/ajeetsharma/Desktop/Study/Fastlane/FastLaneDemo2/fastlane/gitHubKey", keychain_password:"qwerty", git_branch:"master")


  end

  desc "Build binary"
  lane :build do
  signing 
   
  end

  desc "Release"
  
    lane :release do
   
   build 
   
  end

end



end
```

After using these command:

```
$fastlane match appstore
$fastlane match development
```

Certificates and provisioning profile has been created successfully and saved in git repository.

[image]

When I am using this command:

```
$fastlane ios signing
```

Then My terminal is stuck with this status:

[image]

Nothing is happening after this even I waited 30-40 min.

But it is not working.
Not able to understand what is the issue ?